# Then or Than, Which to use when comparing time?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, comparatives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it absolutely necessary to use “than” over “then” in a comparison?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14613/is-it-absolutely-necessary-to-use-than-over-then-in-a-comparison)

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

> "I have been here for less then six months."

or

> "I have been here for less than six months."

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary? What did it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use 'than', not 'then' while comparing anything (not only time) in this fashion.

Eg.

> "He is greater than 6 ft."
>
> "He always scores better than you."

So,

> "I have been here for less than six months."

is correct.

Comment: Despite the fact that it is referring to time?

Comment: @shachna, yes... see the updated answer