# "Smarter than me" or "smarter than I"?

Tags: grammaticality, personal-pronouns

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [I can run faster than _____. (1) him (2) he?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/i-can-run-faster-than-1-him-2-he)
>   [“like I” or “like me”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/like-i-or-like-me)

Which of these is correct and why?

I always assumed it followed the rule of "which would be correct if you inserted the verb", eg. Smarter than I am vs. Smarter than me am, in which case the former would obviously be correct.

But thinking more about it, I'm not sure...