# "The new guys are dressed a lot nicer than we/us"

Tags: personal-pronouns, comparisons, grammatical-case

Does anyone know the correct word choice between "we" and "us", and explain the reason why? Thanks!

Comment: Both are correct, but "than us" is more common. Follow [the link](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/i-can-run-faster-than-1-him-2-he) for details.

Answer (score -2):

The new guys are dressed a lot nicer than we are dressed.

Comment: Is the second "are dressed" necessary?

Comment: No; it's optional. Terpy included it as a hint for how you know whether to use "we" or "us". You wouldn't say "than us were dressed", so you also wouldn't say "than us". In other words, next time you encounter this situation, try completing the sentence in your head, and the correct choice will be clearer.

Comment: This is stuff and nonsense. Different sentence is different. You could likewise "complete" the sentence in a myriad other ways, to "prove" how every single word in it is wrong. There is nothing to complete. The sentence is complete as is. Leave it alone.

Comment: Your comment made me curious, so I read the linked question. In light of the data presented in the canonical answer, I retract my statement.

Comment: This type of analogy would wrongly suggest "They are dressed [like I](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14294)" by analogy with "They are dressed like I am dressed." Also ["The swimmer next to Cavic arrives just before he"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/265500) by analogy with "The swimmer next to Cavic arrives just before he does."