# What is correct: "I don't wake up as soon as him" or "as soon as he"?

Tags: grammar

I guess "he", because I can say "as soon as he does", but I feel like "him" should be correct as well.

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, you can do that, but not in the question portion of the posting.

Comment: That's just a speculation to clear up my issues with it.

Comment: Also related: [“like I” or “like me”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/like-i-or-like-me)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are the subject of the sentence and perform the action, so you would use "him". You would only use the pronoun "he" if that individual is performing the action, for example: "He wakes up before me."

However, on a side note the sentence still sounds a little awkward. I think a better way to express that would be "I don't wake up as early as he does." (In which case the "does" acts as a verb, so both subjects are performing an action)

This link does a good job of explaining the difference: http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-him-and-vs-he/

Comment: I'm sorry, but your first paragraph is plain wrong. 'He' is not the object of the verb. "I don't wake up as early as he does" is the _only_ correct way to say it (although people often say 'as early as him' in casual speech).

Answer (score -1):

There should be a good (canonical) duplicate answer for this question, but I cannot find one. So:

- "As soon as he" is grammatically correct, but it sounds very old-fashioned.
- "As soon as him" is grammatically incorrect, but it is often used instead.
- "As soon as he does" is probably the best choice, since it is both colloquial and grammatically correct.