# Why does it sound incorrect that he like me is a teacher?

Tags: grammar

> He like me is a teacher.

Why does it sound incorrect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["like I" or "like me"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/like-i-or-like-me) The question is not identical, but the principles are the same. If one models on 'He is a teacher just as I am [a teacher], there's obviously a pull towards 'like I' here. But the 'accusative is default' pull is, as often, stronger. Use a pair of commas if you want pauses around the parenthetical, or keep it the way it is if you prefer smooth running text.

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be - He, like me, is a doctor.

Comment: Yes, pauses are definitely necessary to make the meaning clear. You could also say "Like me, he is a doctor/teacher".

Comment: @Kate I've found one example of zero punctuation in the first 40 hits in a Google search for  << "he like me is a" -"does he" -"will he" >>, one of dashes, three of brackets, and the great majority, of commas. Zero punctuation _is_ rare round parentheticals (as you say, it's often necessary to clarify or aid parsing). But for short, simple examples, it can be used to effect.