# Does “on behalf of myself” make sense?

Tags: grammar

I often hear the following, particularly during announcements when travelling by rail or air:

> **On behalf of myself** and the rest of the team, I would like to wish
>   you a pleasant journey.

I've always wondered whether this is grammatical. I found **[this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10684/if-you-are-talking-on-behalf-of-you-and-someone-else-what-is-the-correct-usag)**, which discusses how to form such a sentence, but it still seems unusual to me even if it is correct. Something closer to the following would seem more rational:

> **On behalf of the whole team**, I would like to wish you a pleasant journey.

This is because the *whole team* is not speaking. Contrast this to the first example in which the speaker claims to be speaking on behalf of himself.

Can either of these sentences be used to mean the same thing? Is one preferred over the other?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the first version, and I actually prefer it.  It, of course, violates the "modesty" rule that you shouldn't mention yourself before "the whole team", but that's not a syntax violation.  Yes, it may be redundant, but English is full of redundancies, and life's too short to worry about most of them.

Comment: It would not be unusual to say: *John is speaking on his own behalf, not for anyone else*. It is idiomatic and has meaning. So why not *On behalf of myself and the rest of the team*?

Comment: I prefer the first version in the context you give. It emphasises the speaker's gratitude without demeaning the rest of the team; the 'modesty rule' hardly applies when you're leading the giving. This pragmatic device (here, for emphasising an individual whose gratitude is especially felt) is obviously not incorrect: 'On behalf of John and the rest of the team, who are sadly unable to be here today, I would like to wish you a pleasant journey.' I wouldn't normally use 'On behalf of myself ...' alone.

Answer (score 7):

The first version is a bit redundant, but there's nothing *wrong* with it. They both mean the same thing, with the first putting a bit of emphasis on the fact that *you* are wishing them a pleasant journey- which I think is why this technically redundant form is used; it's a way to emphasize that you speak for yourself and not just the team, and that you personally agree with what you're saying.

Comment: There’s nothing really redundant about the first version either, if you look at it logically. _Myself_ represents one member of the team; _the rest of the team_ represents, well, all the others. So together they are equivalent to _the whole team_. But if you remove either constituent, they would no longer represent the whole team, so there is no real redundancy; they’re just different ways of saying the same thing. It’s similar to how saying “Scandinavia, Iceland, and Finland” means the same as “the Nordic countries”—neither is really _redundant_, just differently worded.

Answer (score -1):

“On behalf of myself” makes no sense. “On behalf of” means “ representing someone.”  You’re not representing yourself. You are yourself! Better to say, “on behalf of (someone), I am pleased to...”

Comment: Since it is such a common ideom, why does it make no sense to you?