# What is the answer to the question "Who came yesterday?" — "I" or "Me"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, pronouns, personal-pronouns

> **Duplicate of:**
>   [Who wants ice-cream?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/who-wants-ice-cream)

What is the answer to the question:

> Who came yesterday?

Is it "I" or "Me"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do I use "I" instead of "me?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313/when-do-i-use-i-instead-of-me), and [Which is correct "you and I" or "you and me"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me), and many others.

Comment: @Alenanno: _Me_ is informal in this case ...

Comment: @Homam: check out these excellently informative answers by an actual linguist: [one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/should-i-put-myself-last-me-and-you-vs-you-and-me/1197#1197), [two](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/who-wants-ice-cream/4655#4655), [three](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313/when-do-i-use-i-instead-of-me#760).

Comment: @Akram: first of all, *me* is extremely widespread even in formal contexts. Secondly and most importantly, "informal" is not "wrong", contrary to what you suggest in your answer.

Comment: @Reg: Thanks for confirmation. I wasn't sure, but I didn't find it "wrong" to say "Me." if a professor calls you for example or in some business meeting (if you can consider them formal contexts).

Answer (score -6):

The right answer is *I*. From *I did*.

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong. The unmarked form for pronouns in English is the objective, not the nominative one. This has been discussed [over](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1133//1197#1197) and [over](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/313//760#760) and [over](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4556//4655#4655) and [over](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/10643/) again.