# "It's me" or "It's I"

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which one is correct to say: “It's me” or “It's I”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10643/which-one-is-correct-to-say-its-me-or-its-i)

Which of these is correct? "*It's me*" or "*It's I*".

I hear these both colloquially but need the grammatically correct statement if one is preferable over the other.