# It wasn't someone or I vs. It wasn't me or someone (usage in denial statement)

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-case, disjunction

If one was to state that neither him or another person committed a certain act, how would that be phrased with proper grammar?

ex. Who broke that window?

It wasn't me or Steve.

vs.

It wasn't Steve or I.

Comment: How would you phrase it if Steve were not involved?  Why would Steve's presence affect what first-person pronoun you use?

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/q/10643.

Answer (score -3):

How about:

> Neither of us.

Or:

> It wasn't Steve **nor** I.

This is poor grammar:

> It wasn't me or Steve.

Comment: There is nothing grammatical wrong with the thing you pretend is poor.