# He must decide who/whom to be. Which is correct?

Tags: grammatical-case, whom, be, who

Which of the following two sentences is correct?

> He must decide **who** to be.
>
> He must decide **whom** to be.

I can think of arguments for both sides, but I'm not sure.

To elaborate, is *who(m)* the object of *decide*, the subject of *be*, or the object of *be*? Does the infinitive form of *be* have any bearing on the answer? And is there anything else to consider about the position or role of *who(m)* in this particular sentence that would inform the answer?

The answers to the linked question [What’s the rule for using “who” and “whom” correctly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-s-the-rule-for-using-who-and-whom-correctly) say to "substitute *he* and *him* for *who* and *whom*." However, that doesn't give a clear answer in this context, because neither of those pronouns sounds right: "He must decide to be he"? "He must decide to be him"? Normally we'd use a reflexive pronoun here ("He must decide to be himself") and it's not clear what case that corresponds to.

Comment: Being the object of *decide*, it's *whom*. A construction using *who* would be *He must decide who he is*, where the whole clause is taken to be the object.

Comment: It's actually "who" in this case. The important verb is "to be", which doesn't take an object.

Comment: @Anonym It's not that simple question.

Comment: Since whom is often misused as an *overcorrection*, the current recommendation is, *When in doubt, use who.* That way, if you make a mistake (either way), it will seem less pretentious.

Comment: @ralph.m: wait, *to be* doesn't take an object? So you can't be, um, anything? You can't be president? You can't be him? You can't be whomever you want? You can't even be yourself? Please do tell that to your kids.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: "Be" takes a complement, not an object. I think it should be "be whoever you want".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accusative_case) about the *accusative case* explains that

> Modern English, which almost entirely ***lacks declension*** in its nouns,
>   does not have an explicitly marked accusative case even in the
>   pronouns. Such forms as ***whom, them, and her*** derive rather from the old
>   Germanic dative forms, of which the -m and -r endings are
>   characteristic.

Now, whether to use *who* or *whom* in your sentence entirely depends on which case should be used, accusative (whom) or nominative (who).

In English, it is grammatically correct to use *nominative* after the verb *to be* as in

> It's he who stole my car. It's they who told me the truth. It's she
>   who lied to me.

However, we know that ["It's me" (using the accusative case after *to be*)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10643/which-one-is-correct-to-say-its-me-or-its-i) is broadly used in English. But it is just a few exceptions.

In your sentence, it is appropriate to use the ***nominative*** case as it is the complement of ***to be***. If you divide the sentence into two parts:

> He must decide / He should be ***who*** => He must ask who he should be => He must decide ***who*** to be.

in the same way as:

> He must decide / He should meet ***whom*** => He must decide whom he should meet => He must decide ***whom*** to meet.
>
> He must ask / She is ***who*** => He must ask ***who*** she is. (This question cannot be shortened with ***wh-word*** + ***to-infinitive*** as the subjects are not  same.)

We don't ask,

> *Whom is he? or *Who is him?
>
> *Whom am I? or *Who am me?

because whom and him/me are the ***accusative*** case and can't be a complement of the verb *be* in this case.

Note: "He must decide who he wants to be" is more idiomatic than "he must decide who to be".

Comment: If this is the case, then why do we say *I want him to be here* instead of **I want he to be here*? Why do we say *I consider them to be useless* instead of **I consider they to be useless*?

Comment: @Anonym Because want and consider are ***transitive*** verbs. *To be* is not a transitive verb.

Comment: @Rathony: I think the verb Anonym is arguing is analogous to *want* and *consider* is *decide*, which is transitive in the sentence in question.

Comment: @RJH The verb ***decide*** takes *who to be* as an object, not *who* itself. That is well explained above.

Comment: @Anonym: Interesting. Arguably, however, *who(m) to be* is the object of *decide*, just like *who he is*. There is also the question of whether, with the addition of the complements *here* and *useless*, your examples are actually analogous. So maybe it's not so cut and dried. Perhaps in support of your contention, to consider somebody to be something is like deciding oneself to be someone, so that we can consider *he must decide (himself) to be someone, but who(m)*, or simply *he must decide himself to be who(m)*, but the intercession of the extra pronoun complicates things.

Comment: @Rathony: Maybe. But that doesn't make your point about what's transitive and what's not a meaningful argument. In any event I'm not arguing definitively for one side or the other. I'm just saying it's not that simple a question either way. Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_(pronoun)#Ambiguous_cases) and see if you can't see it both ways.

Comment: @RJH We are not talking about the Shakespeare era English. English was not that well established at the time.

Comment: @Rathony: That's not a useful argument, and anyway you completely missed the point. The article claims that *Beethoven, whom you believe [or whom you believe to be] a great composer, wrote only one opera* is correct. Why is it *whom* here instead of *who* when we have the verb *to be*? Why can the pronoun be the object of *believe* but not *decide*? Feel free to convince me with a better argument than "Shakespeare". I'm not arguing for the sake of argument. I'm genuinely questioning. Certainly no one has explained it here yet.

Comment: @RJH Contrast "I believe ***him*** to be a great composer" with "I believe ***he*** to be a great composer". Which case is it? It should be the accusative case. Contrast "Beethoven, ***who*** I believe is a great composer" with "Beethoven, ***whom*** I believe is a great composer". Which case is it? It should be the nominative case.

Comment: @Rathony: I'm on board with that side of it. That's the easy part. Now: *He **considers** himself to be who(m)? He **decides** (himself) to be who(m)? He must be someone. He must decide who(m).* Given that *to be* is a copula, theoretically it shouldn't change the form of the pronoun. So if *himself* is an object here, so should *who(m)* be, arguably. Frankly I like *who*, but I don't see how *whom* can can be easily dismissed as incorrect. That's all.

Comment: @RJH I understand well your point. Let's say my son wants to follow my career. Then, contrast "My son (he) decided to be me/I" with "He decided to be like me". The former is not idiomatic and sounds awkward as there is only one "me". I know people use "accusative" after "to be", but not in the case of "who". I don't think there is any easy way to explain it more clearly other than you have to figure it out under the grammatical principle. Some colloquialism should not be involved in deciding this.

Comment: @Rathony: The principle that I'm thinking about is that what goes into a copulative must come out, so while the (prescribed) pattern is nominative-copula-nominative, it's also accusative-copula-accusative, because it should be the same on both sides. So let's say there's some question as to whether a woman I've met only briefly is a teacher or the principal at my child's school. If, given the evidence, I decide *her* to be the principal (and not *she*), someone could conceivably ask, *you've decided her to be whom?* The verb *decide* has a bearing on case here, I'd suggest, despite *to be*.

Comment: @RJH I don't think it has anything to do with the verb *decide*, rather increasing trend of using accusative after the verb *be*. I don't think I can explain it in further detail. Shall we stop here if you don't mind? I fully understand your point and I am not saying you are wrong. :-)

Comment: @Rathony: Cheers. :-)

Comment: @RJH I always appreciate your constructive comments and points. You, too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It would be

> He must decide who to be.

because

> who

is a [**subjective pronoun**](http://web.ku.edu/~edit/subjective.html) and

> to be

is a verb, and subjective pronouns have to be the subject of a verb. Whom is an [**objective pronoun**](http://web.ku.edu/~edit/objective.html), so it would have to be the object of decide, which it isn't. If it were to be the object of decide, the sentence would have to be written thus:

> He must decide whom he will be.

This is an example, and

> will be

could be exchanged for

> is to be,
>   should be,

etc. as the writer desires.

Comment: Not that I disagree with your conclusion, but the way you started your argument sounds like circular reasoning: (1) *who* is a subject, (2) subjects are subjects of verbs, (3) *to be* is a verb, thus (4) *who* has to be correct.

Comment: If this is the case, then why do we say *I want him to be here* instead of **I want he to be here*? Why do we say *I consider them to be useless* instead of **I consider they to be useless*?

Comment: The verb tense of *to be* doesn't necessarily change the pronoun case, given that *to be* is a copula – even with the additional instance of the pronoun *he*. In the end, the sense is arguably still *to be who(m)*. Whether to use the subjective or objective case in this sense is much [disputed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_(pronoun)#Ambiguous_cases). There are arguments for both, which are further complicated by the fact that *whom* itself is falling out of favor. I think that traditional grammars would prescribe *who he will be*, not *whom he will be*.

Comment: @Michael It was past midnight for me when I wrote that, and though it made perfect sense then, I can see problems with it now. If you saw the links I made, you will see what I was basing my point off of. The problem is that I said that "whom" would have to be the object of decide.  This is not true; it should then be the object of the subject, He. You could also write the sentence so: He should decide to be who/whom? where who/whom is the object of the subject He, being the person he is deciding about becoming. And we would put "him" there instead: He should decide to be him.

Comment: @wariya -- I agree that this is a tricky case. I also did not intend harm with my comment. I actually find circular reasoning funny since it reminds me of the film *Idiocracy*. Sometimes we understand a point better than we can express quickly and accurately in words. This happens to me too.

Comment: @Anonym -- In your example *I want him to be here*, *him* is the *indirect* (dative) object of *want*. You know this partly because you can drop the word and still have the sentence be grammatically correct, albeit of a different meaning. Interestingly, a dative object should always be in object case, so *whom* would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

When fronted "who" is a predicative complement, as it is in your example, it is always nominative.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted here. I was about to upvote, after checking your claim, but the lack of attribution (and this one seems not to be from CGEL) of this near-enough quote held me back.

Answer (score 0):

***He must decide who to be.***

This is correct grammatically (but as noted elsewhere, it is not a sentence that you would see in general use, if ever).

***He must decide who to appoint.*** // ***He must decide whom to appoint.***

The latter is grammatically correct, however "whom" can run the risk of sounding archaic and/or pretentious, even when used in the proper way, so it is often reserved for really obvious instances where "who" looks or sounds distinctly incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

> He must decide who(m) to be.

We can tell that “who(m)” in this sentence isn't the subject of "to be" because the meaning of the sentence requires the subject to be "he" (or an empty element with "he" as the antecedent). It means the same thing as "He must decide who he will be" and not the same thing as "He must decide who will be."

I think this sentence has the same structure as a sentence like

> He must decide [to be an adult].

In other words, the pronoun “who(m)” is the complement of the verb "to be". 
This corresponds perfectly with the meaning of the sentence.
The position of the pronoun “who(m)” in front of “to be” is regular due to the process of fronting. If we mark the original position of the pronoun with a “trace” t<sub>1</sub>, we get the following representation of the structure:

> He must decide [who(m)<sub>1</sub> to be t<sub>1</sub>].

Now, as mentioned in the question, both nominative and accusative pronouns sound odd after “decide to be” for semantic reasons.

However, if we compare this to other sentences containing "to be" with similar structure but different semantics, we find that the nominative seems to have been historically prescribed in this grammatical context. *[Correct English](https://books.google.com/books?id=jVRJAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA352&lpg=RA1-PA352&dq=which%20is%20correct:%20%22to%20be%20me%22%20%22to%20be%20I%22&source=bl&ots=XSXM6ezkXu&sig=A-RFEcgBm_X5C9eNHbjFvu6MjF8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii36qchf7LAhVBvYMKHd3ODn4Q6AEINjAE#v=onepage&q=which%20is%20correct%3A%20%22to%20be%20me%22%20%22to%20be%20I%22&f=false)*, Volumes 20-21, edited by Josephine Turck Baker, from 1919, says that the following sentences are "correct":

> - It was supposed to be I who made the error.
> - It was thought to be he to whom the speaker referred.
> - I should like to be he/she.

I think this addresses [Anonym’s point](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294223/he-must-decide-who-whom-to-be-which-is-correct#comment659344_294230) about “I want him to be here”: quite simply, Baker treats “to be” differently depending on whether it’s explicitly preceded by an accusative pronoun. And in a sentence like "He must decide to be an adult", there is no accusative pronoun, so Baker (and presumably other prescriptivists like her) would consider it incorrect to make the complement of "to be" accusative in this context.

As [Rathony](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/140086/rathony) said in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294223/he-must-decide-who-whom-to-be-which-is-correct#comment659360_294230), “The verb ***decide*** takes *who to be* as an object, not *who* itself.”

The fact that “decide” works this way is simply a fact about this particular verb in modern English.

Now, all of this rests on my original analysis of the structure of the sentence, which might be wrong (I'm not a syntax expert), although [BillJ](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/141248/billj)'s [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/294266/77227) seems to assume more or less the same structure I've presented here.

"Who" certainly sounds OK here, so even if I'm not 100% certain "whom" would be wrong, I'm confident enough to recommend "who" over "whom" here. As [medica](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/58761/medica) said in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294223/he-must-decide-who-whom-to-be-which-is-correct#comment659337_294223),

> Since *whom* is often misused as an overcorrection, the current
>   recommendation is, *When in doubt, use who.* That way, if you make a
>   mistake (either way), it will seem less pretentious.

Answer (score -1):

In this context, "who he is" and "who to be" have the same meaning, just in different tenses. Assuming tense alone does not change the structure, they should both use *who*. Moreover, if *be* is here a [linking verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_verb), it may not be correct to assume it can be transitive. Only a transitive verb should need an object pronoun such as *whom*. For example, in "He must decide whom to marry", *marry* is a transitive verb taking *whom* as an object.

On the other hand, it appears that *who*/*whom* here is in the *dative* case, or the case of an *indirect object*. Generally speaking, indirect objects are always supposed to be in object form. One of the key features of indirect objects is that they can be omitted while keeping the sentence fully grammatical: "He must decide whom to be" -> "He must decide to be".

Comment: The infinitive (*to be*) is not a tense, since it is, in both name and definition, non-finite.

Comment: Strictly speaking, your point may be correct about an infinitive not being in an official tense, but for practical purposes, does it not represent the unspecific tense? For example, on a multiple choice exam, is the "None of the above" option not still an *answer*? It may not be specific, but choosing this option is certainly different than choosing nothing.