# Does the verb 'to be' have a direct object in English? And do all prepositions create a direct object too?

Tags: grammar

For instance, would the correct sentence be 'whom is he?' or 'who is he?'?

Further, would 'to', 'for', 'with', and so on all be followed by a 'whom' or a 'him'; rather than a 'who' or a 'he'?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: [Who/Whom do you want to be?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/441163)

Comment: (1) _Be_ does not have a direct object; _Who is he?_ is correct. (2) Prepositions have objects, but not direct objects; only transitive verbs have direct objects. Also, some prepositions are intransitive and work on the side as adverbs or phrasal verb particles.

Comment: @John Lawler Don't rule out Prepxit.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> (1) *Be* does not have a direct object; *Who is he?* is correct. (2) Prepositions have objects, but not direct objects; only transitive verbs have direct objects. Also, some prepositions are intransitive and work on the side as adverbs or phrasal verb particles.