# Object pronouns

Tags: pronouns, objects

I've managed to get myself confused about using object pronouns in some cases. I'm unsure whether it's correct usage, or incorrect, but very common, usage

Q: Who is hungry?
A: Me
or should it be:
A: I

If I put a verb in  ("I am"), then it's obvious, but without the verb, "I" am still the subject of my answer "I" am the one who's hungry. So, is "me" or "I" correct? If "me", then why? (I'd say "me")

Or "The worst player on the football team is I" or "... is me"?

Again, I'd say "...is me", but I think it should be "...is I", because the verb "to be" is intransitive so doesn't take an object". But "...is I" looks wrong...

There are similar cases where "is I" looks more correct (eg "it is I who is confused" - although now I'm thinking should be that be "it is I who **am** confused"? Argh. I'm even more confused!). Even in that case "it is me who's confused" would be common.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which one is correct to say: "It's me" or "It's I"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10643/which-one-is-correct-to-say-its-me-or-its-i). The conversational deletion from "It's me" to "Me' follows. Perceived 'rules' have thankfully been rewritten in line with how native Anglophones actually use the language. See the NOAD entry.

Comment: @Edwin, In Indian schools, if we write 'me' he/she will lose marks.  They distinguish  this way: Who is hungry?  I am hungry; Whom did she give food? Me; She gave me.

Comment: "Whom did she give food?" has been ungrammatical as long as I've been alive, in the UK (and, I'd guess, in the US, Australia...). The answer to "To whom did she give food" (rare) or "Who did she give food to?"  would be "Me". The answer to "Who is hungry?" is "I am", or informally "Me", but _never_ nowadays "I." // 'Indian English' and 'British English' (though they're not totally well-defined, hence the scare quotes) have drifted quite a way apart.

Answer (score -1):

Solve the problem just by adding *am*.  *Who is hungry?* "I am!" is correct but not stilted as if you were saying, "It is I."

That's a toughy—how to be correct without sounding priggish.  But it's a fun challenge. When you have the option, use contractions to make it informal. I tilt towards, "It's I who's confused."  It seems to move me along the fasted!