# Older than me (or I)?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, comparisons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can run faster than _____. (1) him (2) he?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/i-can-run-faster-than-1-him-2-he)

Is it correct to say, "She's older than me" or "She's older than I?" I almost always hear people say the former (me). If I remember correctly my grade school grammar, though, the test to apply is to say the sentence out in full: "She's older than I (am old)." In that case, the subject form I seems to be correct.

I've often wondered and would appreciate a definitive answer.

Comment: “Please see my excellent, data-driven answer [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/i-can-run-faster-than-1-him-2-he/3483#3483)”, he said modestly.