# Confusion regarding "I" and "me"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, pronouns, comparisons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can run faster than _____. (1) him (2) he?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/i-can-run-faster-than-1-him-2-he)

Which one is correct?

> He is taller than I.
>   He is taller than me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can run faster than _____. (1) him (2) he?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/i-can-run-faster-than-1-him-2-he) and related to [Should I say "not I" or "not me"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/should-i-say-not-i-or-not-me) and other ones.