# Use of "me" vs. "I" in comparisons

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, grammatical-case, comparisons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can run faster than _____. (1) him (2) he?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/i-can-run-faster-than-1-him-2-he)

I was using this sentence with an ease until my teacher scolded that this is wrong. He said to use *I* in place of *me* as comparison is being done between two subjects. So *me* is wrong according to him:

> He is wiser than **me**.

He said to use:

> He is wiser than **I**.

Which sounds more appropriate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can run faster than \_\_\_\_\_. (1) him (2) he?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/i-can-run-faster-than-1-him-2-he) Also see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38593/confusion-regarding-i-and-me

Comment: I agree it's a duplicate, but Barrie's answer here is better than any of the answers on the other question! (There is an answer which tends towards what Barrie has said, but doesn't get as far as providing an authoritative answer)