# "You know more about this than me/I"

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-case, comparisons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [I can run faster than _____. (1) him (2) he?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/i-can-run-faster-than-1-him-2-he)

Which is correct?

> You know more about this than **me**.
>
> You know more about this than **I**.

The second sounds unnatural, but I think it is correct because a trailing *know* is implied.

Comment: Depends in part on what meaning you want.  The first is a correct way to say "You know more about this subject than you know about me", and the second correctly says "You know more about this subject than I know about it."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is both are correct. The first **than** is used as a *preposition* while the second one is used as a *conjunction*.

Note **however**, to me, the first sentence means you know more about this than you know about me while the second one means you know more about this than I know about this.

Comment: If you meant 'You know more about this than you know about me', then that's what you'd say. In any normal conversation, 'You know more about this than me' can only mean that your knowledge of the subject under discussion is greater than mine.

Comment: @BarrieEngland I'm not sure. I might have over-analysed the sentence. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Wait...how about I like you better than him? Either way seems fine to me.

Comment: In the sort of conversation in which that is likely to occur the meaning will usually be clear from the context. If it isn't the speakers will sort it out.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Communication is easy while grammar is hard :)

Comment: Grammar isn't hard. By the age of five, childen have learnt most of the grammar of their native language without effort. What is hard is understanding how grammar works.

Comment: I suppose the meaning of the first version would depend on how you emphasized it.  I'd probably say "You know more about this than you know about me" if I wanted to accuse someone of knowing some other subject better than me.

Answer (score 12):

The first uses *than* as a preposition having *me* as its complement. The second uses *than* as a conjunction to introduce the elliptical clause *I (do)*. ‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’ reports that:

> Research associated with the *Longman Grammar* (1999) showed that
>   speakers mostly use *than* (and *as*) as prepositions (i.e. with a
>   following object pronoun) and only rarely with a following subject
>   pronoun. Fiction writers make about equal use of the two
>   constructions, while academic writers use neither.

No one need hesitate to say *You know more about this than me.*

Comment: I have downvoted all the answers and upvoted only yours, because only you got it correct. Great job, Barrie!

Comment: This relates to http://english.stackexchange.com/a/17084/50720

Answer (score 7):

The second sentence is, indeed, the correct one. If in doubt, always try to fill in the missing words - just as you did.

> You know more about this than I **do/know**.

If you don't, your sentences might get misinterpreted. Consider this example

> Sara likes cake more than **(she likes)** me.

or

> Sara likes cake more than I **(like cake)**.

Comment: If by that you mean 'You know more about this than me' is incorrect, then it seems from the 'Longman Grammar' evidence (see my answer) that most native speakers are speaking incorrectly.