# "Than I" or "Than Myself"

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can run faster than _____. (1) him (2) he?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/i-can-run-faster-than-1-him-2-he)

Which is grammatically correct?

> My friends seem to be having more fun than *I, Me, Myself, and Them*

Also,

> Good people are always ready to help those who are not as fortunate as *Theirs, Them, They, Us*

Comment: I'd pick *me* for the first one, and use *themselves* for the second.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the first sentence:

- *Me* is the most natural choice: *My friends seem to be having more fun than me*.
- *I* in this context would be old fashioned and sits uncomfortably with a modern phrase like *having fun*.  (It would be more natural in something like *Is there more pitiable a wretch than I?*, where both the choice of words and the sentiment itself are old fashioned.)
- *Myself* is odd here.  American English seems to make more use of reflexives, but generally for second person, I think, that is, substituting *yourself* for *you*. My guess is that this indirectness may be something of a politeness strategy.  If so, then even these dialects might resist use of *myself* here (no need to be polite to yourself).
- *Them* is of course fine, but it would not refer back to you, the speaker.  It would refer to some other salient group.

For the second sentence:

- The most common pronouns here would be *them* or *themselves*. (There's a dialect split here, but I can't recall the details.)
- Oddly, *they* doesn't sound old fashioned here to me, just wrong.  I feel it needs to be followed by *are* (*not as fortunate as they are*).  Maybe other native speakers can weigh in here.
- *Theirs* is out. It's a possessive pronoun, and, so, would give the sentence meaning that good people help people less fortunate than something previously mentioned that they possess.
- Finally, *us* is fine, but it implies that you are not one of the good people and that good people use your standard of living as the benchmark for their altruism.  If you want to say that, that's your business ;-)

Comment: Great answer.  re: _Myself_ - I know that we're supposed to recognize that the language evolves and all, but I have to say it drives me nuts when people use "myself" when they mean "me".  They think they're sounding formal and clever when in fact they are just sounding dumb.

Comment: *They’re having more fun than I am” does not sound old-fashioned nor does it sit uncomfortably in the mouth.

Comment: @Daniel Harbour, Are you the "Kiowa" guy? If you are, you'll understand me. If not, sorry!

Comment: Second sentence: 'They' is fine if followed by 'are'. see tchrist above (+1 from me) for 'I' equivalent.

Comment: @tchrist: I agree that *They're having more fun than I am* is fine (in contrast to *They're having more fun that I*).  Didn't mean to imply otherwise, so thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @AlexB. Yeah, I guess you could call me that...  I came across the stackexchange sites because I'm editing a collection of Kiowa texts just now and needed some help with tex encoding.

Comment: @DanielHarbour, I hope you didn't take offence - it meant to be a indirect compliment. Have you already seen Linguistics SE http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/? It'd be nice to have you there.

Comment: @AlexB. Ta, I'll check it out.  (Of course, no offence taken!)

Comment: I'm totally fine with "more fun than I" and "those who are not as fortunate as they". Neither is old fashioned. They have clear meaning that is actually important in cases like "I love you more than he" vs. "I love you more than him". If you *want* to use the accusative, go ahead, but don't say the other is wrong, because it's not, even if it sounds funny to you.