# Correct logical comparison: "Less fortunate than I am" or "less fortunate than myself"?

Tags: grammaticality

I am trying to write a sentence like this:

"I want to help those who are less fortunate than I am."

I am not sure about the last part and whether I am comparing the right things:
There's three versions that I was debating:

1. "...less fortunate than I am."
2. "... less fortunate than myself."
3. "...less fortunate than I.

I think it is the first version "I am" and that it might actually be equivalent to saying "myself." I am not sure.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to ELU and thank you for your question.  Ideally you need to explain why you are uncertain and what steps you have taken to find an answer yourself.  However, I will say that your first version is the best of the three, especially if you are writing in a formal context.  However, if you are writing to a friend of casual acquaintance, 3) would be the more familiar, even thou some might say that using the 'object' case of the pronoun, "me" is strictly incorrect.  However, that is what most of would say.  "Myself" is the one to avoid: it is rather stilted.

Comment: No harm stopping at *I want to help those who are less fortunate*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Than I" or "Than Myself"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71248/than-i-or-than-myself) ',,, than I am' and '... than me' are also covered here and at the duplicate..

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think you just want to say: "I want to help those who are less fortunate" the "myself" or "than I am" is implied -- they are less fortunate relative to you.

Comment: Ah, okay yeah that makes sense. Thank you!