# He has more money than [her/she/she does]?

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can run faster than _____. (1) him (2) he?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/i-can-run-faster-than-1-him-2-he)

What's the right was to say here?

> He has more money than **she**.

or

> He has more money than **her**.

or

> He has more money than **she does**.

Comment: While we're at it, how about: "He has more money than **she has**." The second two seem correct to me. I can't speak to the first, but the ending ( *is* / *has* /etc.) is implied, so I think it's grammatical.

Comment: *She does* vs. *she has* is perhaps worthy of a separate question (not sure if *that* one would be a dupe as well), but the *she* vs. *her* part has been covered before.