# "He is better than _____." (1) I (2) I am?

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-case, comparisons

Which of the following constructions is / are correct?

- He is better than I.
- He is better than I am.

PS: I'm unfamiliar with this site and its workings, so forgive me if my question fails to follow the community guidelines. If there are any improvements I can make to the question, please do point them out.

Comment: Thanks for your question. It is a fine question; one that meets with community guidelines. However, an equivalent question has already been asked. If the answers to http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3447 don't fully answer your question, please feel free to update your question to explain what's still confusing.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that question. I notice that the my question has been asked by the OP in the third point, but as far as I can see, it has not been addressed directly.

Comment: @nohat: I'm not completely convinced. That one is mostly about *he/him*, but OP here isn't asking about *me/I*. The matter of *"...than he **can**"* was barely mentioned.

Comment: I see. Can you explain why you would think that only one of them could be correct?

Comment: I think most people would say omitting the *"am"* here is just a bit formal or stilted. We usually *do* include it. (or, we say *"He is better than **me**"* anyway! :)

Comment: @nohat I've been using both forms, so I thought there's a chance one of them violates the rules of grammar. No other reason.

Comment: @Vicky Chijwani: In most contexts, it would be more natural to use *"than me"*. But you should probably forget about plain *"than I"* - it's never necessary, and would often sound awkward/stilted.

Comment: ...nohat notwithstanding, I think this is a *good* question about a fine point of idiomatic usage, only loosely related to the *he/him, I/me* distinction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I disagree about *than I*; I myself prefer it, and it certainly *is* necessary in precise and formal contexts.  But you are certainly right that this is a good question, perhaps better than OP realizes.

Comment: @TimLymington: I'm surprised you prefer the elided form. Per David Wallace's comment below, perhaps *you know better than I*, but that doesn't sound very natural to me. I don't think it makes than much difference if the elided verb is *am, do, can*, or whatever - I think it still sounds pretty "starchy" if you omit it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I myself think a simple comparison doesn't require a verb, so it isn't an elision at all.  And certainly it sounds starchy (or 'proper English' as some would say; can we compromise on *formal*?) but that is not 'never necessary'.

Comment: @TimLymington:: Surely. I did say omitting the verb is *"**just a bit** formal or stilted"*, and at the time I was specifically addressing OP. I have no problem using the form myself, *in the right context* - I just thought if OP's not a native speaker he might appreciate a simple "safe" rule. Turns out he just wondered if dropping the verb was somehow "ungrammatical" (which was addressed by the *possible duplicate* answers anyway), but I thought this question could stand independently largely because of that formal/informal issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are both grammatical, the first being a truncated form of the second. In both, *than* functions as a conjunction. However, *He is better than I* sounds hopelessly formal, at least in British English. The usual form is the equally grammatical *He is better than me*, where *than* functions as a preposition. When a preposition is followed by a pronoun, the pronoun is in the accusative case.

Comment: This is one case where prescriptive language mavens still seem to rule the roost. Google Books ["works harder than I"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22works+harder+than+I%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):5050 results, ["works harder than me"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22works+harder+than+me%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):279 results. But if I try to page through them, there are actually only 44 and 42 results respectively, and many of those 44 are in fact grammarians setting out their idea of "correct" usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: And you might expect the more formal construction in books than in speech.

Comment: Precisely. I'm solidly behind your *"**He is better than I** sounds hopelessly formal"*. I think those prescriptivists who say that's the "correct" form are the same ones whose injunction against splitting infinitives it's my mission **to boldly take** issue with.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Descriptivism is no excuse for sloppy grammar!  ;-)

Comment: @Pitarou: 'Sloppy grammar' usually means constructions that the speaker or writer doesn't like.

Answer (score -1):

"He is better than I" is not the correct way of saying it.. neither would "He is better than I am" sound correct. It would actually be "He is better than me".

Comment: "better than I" may sound stilted, but I don't think it's *incorrect*.

Comment: Many millions of native speakers of English would disagree with this answer.  Some of them may even know better than I.

Comment: But somehow we use "Me" in such sentence that saying "I" doesn't sound right.. May be I am wrong!!

Comment: @Apoorva, David Wallace: I think as Barrie says, the "bare" form *"You know better than I"* is rather stilted/formal, so I'd go for *"me"* there. But [here's the evidence](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=know+better+than+I+how%2Cknow+better+than+me+how&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) that with longer forms such as *"[You] **know better than I how** [to deal with this problem]"*, we don't use *"me"* very often at all (though usage is on the increase).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think that's because in longer forms, it's clear that this has to be a case of ellipsis.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I assume we all accept that whenever plain *"than I"* occurs in such constructions, it's because the following verb has been dropped by ellipsis. I can't see how to interpret you comment as meaning anything other than *"That's because in longer forms we **prefer** to use ellipsis"*. The question is - "why?".