# "He is no different than you and I" or "He is no different than you and me"

Tags: word-choice, phrases, comparatives

I have no difficulty in normal cases knowing whether to say "you and I"or "You and me." But this situation confuses me. On one hand, I can justify **I** by saying there is an implied "are" at the end:

> *He is no different than you and I* **are**

On the other hand, this is a comparative, and if I were to change the sentence up just a bit, it feels like it would be correct to say "me":

> *He is the same as* **me**

Comment: It is ambiguous because 'than' can either act as a preposition or a comparative conjunction. So both options are valid.

Comment: The analysis is problematic. The complement of the preposition "than" can either be analysed as an NP, an immediate constituent of "than", in which case "me" is correct. Alternatively, it could be seen as a reduced comparative clause where "I" is the subject: _...no different (to x) than you and I are different (to x)_.

Comment: I would say that if you are going to use _different_ with _than_, it has to be followed by a clause and _than_ is a conjunction; follow the same rule as for any clause. On the other hand, a comparative with _than_ should be followed by a noun or pronoun object; however, I am old-fashioned and do not subscribe to the "_different_ as comparative" style.

Comment: Yes, but the complement of "different" has been ellipted. In full, it would be something like _He is no different from the others than you or I/me_

Comment: @BillJ I am not sure he had that in mind when he wrote it. There is a tendency in the US to use _different_ as a comparative in the last 30 or 40 years. Personally I would also say different _to_ or _from_.

Comment: Yes, but that still leaves the option of analysing the complement of "than" as an immediate constituent (in which case "me") or a reduced comparative clause (in which case "I"). They are both comparative constructions, the only difference being the complementation.

Comment: @BillJ As you said, problematic. The style is changing, but I am an old dog.

Comment: @Nebulous. I hope you are following all this !

Comment: @V0ight, there is a broader debate as to whether "different than" or "different from" is proper in American English. [Side Note: "Different to," I've read, is widely considered proper in British English].

How would your response have been different if I had asked which is correct, “He is no different from you and I” or “He is no different from you and me?”

Comment: @BillJ - In this example I am using the phrase to mean "he is the same us us," or "all three of us are identical" (within the context)

Comment: @All - To clarify, I want to use one of the two proposed constructions to say that Bill, you, and I are identical (within the context of the rest of the paragraph). Does that help guide your answers?

Comment: You might want to take a look [here.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/i-can-run-faster-than-1-him-2-he/3483#3483)

Comment: That obfuscated even more :-). I'm not certain there is a correct answer.