# Is " him" correct in the sentence " I solved the question more quickly than him"?

Tags: pronouns, comparatives

Is " him" correct in the sentence " I solved the question more quickly than him" ? 
Very often, I see 'objective case' being used. Shouldn't there be the nominative case of pronoun (he) ?

Comment: It is correct if what you mean is that the question was less befuddling than he is.

Comment: Both are possible depending on how the complement of the preposition "than" is analysed. If it seen as a reduced comparative clause with the pronoun as subject:  “… more quickly than [he/him __ ]”,  then both “him” (informal) and “he” (formal) are possible. But the pronoun could also be analysed not as a reduced clause but as an immediate complement of “than” in which case only objective case “me” is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"More quickly" should probably be replaced by quicker.
As for the pronoun at the end, these links might be useful :

- 1

[I can run faster than ______ (him or he)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/i-can-run-faster-than-1-him-2-he)

- 2

[Than 'I' or Than 'me'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43683/than-i-vs-than-me/60289#60289)