# Which one is correct? Him or He?

Tags: word-choice

Which form of this sentence is correct. "No one works as hard as him." Or should it be, "No one works hard as he."?

Comment: Very similar: [I can run faster than _____. (1) him (2) he?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3447)

Answer (score 1):

Standard grammar parses the sentence as:

> No one works as hard as he [works].
>
> I can run faster than he [can run].

In informal speech, however, many speakers treat *as* and *than* more like prepositions than conjunctions and would use *him* in both sentences.

My advice would be to follow standard grammar in writing, but imitate the pattern of those around you whom you need or want to impress with being "like them."