# "I'm not as good as him." versus "I'm not as good as he is."

Tags: grammatical-case, objective-case

Which of these sentences is more grammatical?

"I'm not as good as him."

"I'm not as good as he is."

Comment: This may have already been answered earlier here on ELU, if not on [ell.se] Please see previous related posts. Good Luck.

Comment: @Kris What exactly do I search for? This is a specific example and I don't know what the general case is called.

Comment: [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/i-can-run-faster-than-1-him-2-he) is relevant. It's not an exact duplicate, though.

Comment: Re the post cited by Peter Shor above, that is quite the one to go to. However, I am not sure if the OP is into deep-sea fishing at this stage. Which is why I suggested [ell.se] instead. Both sentences are **grammatically correct**. Usage **varies**.

Comment: (a) It's very unnatural-sounding to say "I'm not as good as he." Even though you will find this as an example of good practice in many 50-year-old school grammars. (b) "I'm not as good as him" is fine and idiomatic in all informal and semi-formal registers. (c) "I'm not as good as he is" keeps everybody happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they are both grammatically correct. I would use "i'm not as good as him"

Comment: Please respect that when commenters have cited duplicates, especially to what appears to be a reasonably common usage, an 'answer' is rarely appropriate. And please look at the Help Center to familiarise yourself with what a _good_ answer on ELU requires – supporting references (or perhaps corpus data suggesting idiomaticity) , linked and attributed.